# VB2015: Get the averages of table 1 field after joining with table 2

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have been trying to get the averages of Quiz1, Quiz2, Exam1, and Exam2 fields of my MIS table after joining it with my Students table.

Here's what each tables have.

MIS have the following fields: StudentID, QUIZ1, QUIZ2, EXAM1, EXAM2, and ClassID

Students have Majors, StudentID, StudentStanding

What I'm trying to accomplish are two things:

1.) Join MIS table with Students Table
2.) Get the Averages of Quizzes 1 and 2, and Exams 1 and 2.

The expected outcome is something like this:

Major --- StudentStanding --- Quiz1Avg --- Quiz2Avg --- Exam1Avg --- Exam2Avg

What I have tried so far:

```
Private Sub Query2_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Query2.Enter
        Dim DC As New OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0;data source=HogCountryUniversity.accdb")
        Dim DS As New DataSet()

        'Joined mis and students but don't know how to get the averages (working)'
        Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select major, studstanding, quiz1, quiz2, exam1, exam2 from [mis] inner join [students] on [mis].studentid = [students].studentid", DC)

        'Display average of Quiz1 from mis table(working)'
        'Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select classid, formatnumber(avg(quiz1),2) as [Quiz1Avg] from mis group by classid", DC)

        'Not working'
        'Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select students.major, students.studstanding, quiz1, quiz2, exam1, exam2 from [mis] inner join on [students].studentid = [mis].studentid", DC)

        'Not working'
        'Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select students.major, students.studstanding, avg(mis.quiz1) as [Quiz1Avg] from quiz1 mis inner join students on mis.studentid = students.studentid group by mis.classid", DC)

        DC.Open()
        DA.Fill(DS)

        DataGridView2.DataSource = DS.Tables(0).DefaultView()
        DC.Close()
    End Sub
```

I know how to get the average of one field from one table and join tables but I don't know how to join the two tables and get the averages of the fields mentioned above.

I am truly stuck and have looked at different stack overflow examples but I still don't get it. Any help/directions/nudges/spoonfeeding is highly appreciated!

Thank you!

EDIT:

I figured it out!

```
 Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select students.major, students.studstanding, formatnumber(avg(mis.quiz1),2) as Quiz1Avg, formatnumber(avg(mis.quiz2),2) as Quiz2Avg, formatnumber(avg(mis.exam1),2) as Exam1Avg, formatnumber(avg(mis.exam2),2) as Exam2Avg from students inner join mis on students.studentid = mis.studentid group by students.major, students.studstanding", DC)
```

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the average of something with a pencil and paper?  Its much the same thing.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: This is an Access DB. This query might be better suited as a view. This means the SQL is stored in the DB as an object you can refer to as a table. You could write this in the DB and then call `SELECT * FROM MyAverageView` from your code. Writing this in the DB would be much easier because you have a designer and/or formatted SQL.